# Problema com onkeyup em input

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Fiz uma pequena função JavaScript para fazer uma busca dinâmica no banco de dados sem dar *refresh* e ela está funcionando, porém acho que há um problema com o `onkeyup`. Ao inserir texto no campo `input` e depois apagar esse texto, a `div#resultado` mostra todos os campos cadastrados no banco de dados (o que não vai ser legal). Há outro método de retirar este *bug* de campo vazio?

```
var req;

// FUNÇÃO PARA BUSCA LOJA
function buscarLojas(valor) {

  // Verificando Browser
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  // Arquivo PHP juntamente com o valor digitado no campo (método GET)
  var url = "busca.php?valor=" + valor;

  // Chamada do método open para processar a requisição
  req.open("Get", url, true);

  // Quando o objeto recebe o retorno, chamamos a seguinte função;
  req.onreadystatechange = function() {

    // Exibe a mensagem "Buscando lojas..." enquanto carrega
    if (req.readyState == 1) {
      document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = 'Buscando lojas...';
    }

    // Verifica se o Ajax realizou todas as operações corretamente
    if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {

      // Resposta retornada pelo busca.php
      var resposta = req.responseText;

      // Abaixo colocamos a(s) resposta(s) na div resultado

      document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = resposta;

    }
  }
  req.send(null);
}
```

Código HTML:

```
<div class="search-box">
  <input type="text" name="busca" id="busca" placeholder="Buscar lojas" onkeyup="buscarLojas(this.value)">
  <span></span>

  <div id="resultado"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui seguindo a dica de colocar uma condição, porém não funcionava com return false, consegui passando null para a `div#resultado`. Para quem estiver com o mesmo problema, segue o código:

```
else{
                document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = null;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Faça um teste pela quantidade de caracteres que o campo tem antes de fazer o pedido dos dados, fazendo apenas quando tem pelo menos 1 caractere escrito:

```
// FUNÇÃO PARA BUSCA LOJA
function buscarLojas(valor) {
     if(valor.length == 0){
           return false;
     }
...
```

Até pode fazer apenas quando tem 2 ou 3 caracteres para que não apareçam tantos resultados, se for o caso.

Answer (score 0):

O onkeyup chama a função quando QUALQUER botao do teclado é pressionado, tanto o *backspace* quanto o *tab*, ou seja se vc apagar ele vai buscar o resultado escrito, como o valor escrito é ""(string vazia) se você estiver usando um *LIKE* ele vai buscar todos os resultados do banco, ou seja, a solução podeira estar no seu servidor *php*, sendo assim, antes de trazer os resultados da busca tente validar se existe valor na variável de busca.